# Cancelación de envío desde formulario hacia servlet no funciona

Tags: javascript, jsp

Estoy haciendo una validación sencilla de campos en un formulario dentro de un **JSP**. Mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form name="login_form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/servletControlador"
          method="post" onsubmit="return validarForm(this);">
    <span id="form_element">Nombre: </span>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Escribir usuario" /><br/>
    <span id="form_element">Contraseña: </span>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="default">
</form>
```

Y la validación es la siguiente:

```
function validarForm(formulario){
    if(formulario.name == "login_form"){ validarLoginForm(formulario);}
}

function validarLoginForm(formulario){
    var usuario = formulario.username;
    if (usuario.value == "" || usuario.value == "Escribir usuario") {
        alert('Debe proporcionar un nombre de usuario válido');
        return false;
    }
    //Validación de la contraseña...

    //Todo ha salido bien
    alert('Redireccionando...');
    return true
}
```

Realizando una llamada en la cual dejo el valor por defecto en el `textbox` del usuario, la alerta que indica que el nombre de usuario no es válido aparece, pero me sigue redireccionando al `servlet`.

Había leído que añadiendo `return` dentro del `onsubmit` del formulario se conseguía el efecto que quiero, pero como verán, ya lo había incluído.

¿Por qué me redirige? Además, me redirige saltándose la alerta de `Redireccionando...`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer la invocación al **JavaScript** entonces?

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: Pon el return antes de `validarLogin`: Es decir, `return validarLogin(formulario);`.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice gugadev, ¿qué función es `validarLogin`? Parece que o bien tienes mal puestos los nombres o faltan funciones en el código. Seguramente puedes ver algún error en la consola que te ayudará con el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por responder.
La solución de gugadev es correcta. No me fijé en que no había puesto el return. ¡Qué error más tonto!
Por otra parte Álvaro, `validarLogin` hace referencia a `validarLoginForm`. Es una errata que no corregí, voy a editarlo ahora mismo.